# android TextView remove implicit margins

Tags: android, margin, textview

Well, this what I have got:

[image]

and this is what I want:

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <TextView
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:text="3"
      android:textSize="500px"
      android:includeFontPadding="false"
      android:paddingTop="0px"
      android:paddingBottom="0px"
      android:paddingLeft="0px"
      android:paddingRight="0px"
      android:layout_marginTop="0px"
      android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
      android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
      android:layout_marginRight="0px"
      android:background="@null"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, I used all magic known: `includeFontPadding`, `background="@null"`, margins, paddings, etc. Did I miss anything?

Comment: try to use linearlayout and in that put textview

Answer (score 0):

try to give height and width to `wrap_contant` instead of `match_parent`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="3" 
        android:textSize="500px" 
android:background="@null"
        android:paddingTop="0px" 
        android:gravity="top">

    </TextView>
```

Comment: did you test it on a device? it doesn't help me. I have a Google Nexus 7 running Android 4.1.2.

Comment: No.. I didn't test it on device.